# Programmatically create an NSViewController without an XIB in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to make a macOS app without using Interface Builder. My project builds and runs, but my primary view controller doesn't seem to be loading its view. That is, the `viewDidLoad()` method is not invoked. I'm using Xcode-beta 8.0 beta 6 (8S201h).

The Swift 3 documentation for `NSViewController` says this about the `view` property:

> If this property’s value is not already set when you access it, the view controller invokes the `loadView()` method. That method, in turn, sets the view from the nib file identified by the view controller’s `nibName` and `nibBundle` properties.
>
> If you want to set a view controller’s view directly, set this property’s value immediately after creating the view controller.

And for `viewDidLoad`:

> For a view controller created programmatically, this method is called immediately after the `loadView()` method completes.

Finally, for `isViewLoaded`:

> A view controller employs lazy loading of its view: Immediately after a view controller is loaded into memory, the value of its `isViewLoaded` property is `false`. The value changes to `true` after the `loadView()` method returns and just before the system calls the `viewDidLoad()` method.

So the documentation leads me to believe it is possible.

---

My project looks like this:

```
 .
 ├── main.swift
 └── Classes
     ├── AppDelegate.swift
     └── Controllers   
         └── PrimaryController.swift
```

**main.swift**

```
import Cocoa

let delegate = AppDelegate()
NSApplication.shared().delegate = delegate
NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let pc = PrimaryController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)!
        print(pc.isViewLoaded)
        pc.view = NSView()
        print(pc.isViewLoaded)
    }
}
```

**PrimaryController.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class PrimaryController: NSViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        print("PrimaryController.loadView")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("PrimaryController.viewDidLoad")
    }
}
```

Building and running a project with the above yields this console output:

```
false
true
```

That is, the view loads for the controller, but the `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` methods are never invoked.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A careful reading of the documentation is enlightening. Specifically:

> If this property’s value is **not already set when you *access* it,** the view controller invokes the `loadView()` method.

Meaning, `loadView()` is only invoked when an attempt is made to read the `view` property *before* the property has a value. Assigning a value to the property directly will bypass the method call.

So if `AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)` is written like this:

```
    let pc = PrimaryController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)!
    print(pc.isViewLoaded)
    let x = pc.view // accessing the view property before it has a value
    print(pc.isViewLoaded)
```

...then `loadView` will be invoked by the system to attempt to load the view:

```
false
PrimaryController.loadView
false
```

Note that `viewDidLoad()` is still not invoked, since no view can be automatically associated with the controller (ie, the nib is `nil` and `PrimaryController.xib` doesn't exist). The correct way to complete the process is to manually load the view in `PrimaryController.loadView()`:

```
print("PrimaryController.loadView")
view = NSView() // instantiate and bind a view to the controller
```

Now the program gives the desired result:

```
false
PrimaryController.loadView
PrimaryController.viewDidLoad
true
```

Answer (score 12):

Minimal setup to make ViewController from code (Swift 4.1)

```
class WelcomeViewController: NSViewController {

   private lazy var contentView = MyCustomClassOrJustNSView()

   override func loadView() {
      view = contentView
   }

   init() {
      super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
   }

   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError()
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems it also works without init implementations.