# NSViewController subclass EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on addSubview

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I am trying to write some code that is cross platform with macOS and iOS. I know this is not the way to do this however I am having to develop things weirdly because I am doing a Playground book and Metal does not work on the simulator.

So I have the following typedefs. There are two sets of them one for when I wish to compile in MacOS and another for iOS

```
//iOS
public typealias View = UIView
public typealias ViewController = UIViewController

//macOS
public typealias View = NSView
public typealias ViewController = NSViewController
```

I only keep one set uncommented at a time.

The following code here works perfectly on iOS

```
public class PVC: NSViewController{
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    public func addView(viewer: NSView) {
        view.addSubview(viewer)
    }
}

let pvc = PVC()
let grid = //UIView initializer
pvc.addView(viewer: grid)
```

However on MacOS the `pvc.addView` line compiles but causes the message `error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.` when run.

I have checked and the grid view is properly formed and could be for example added to the view controller of the default IOS projects if necessary. It is just something about NSViewControllers that is causing this issue.

Comment: Is `view` defined? By default, a view controller lazily loads its view object from its nib/storyboard. So the first use of `view` will attempt to load it from the application bundle. I'd first test to see if `self.view` returns a valid `NSView` object.

Comment: @JamesBucanek it is very wierd if you print view inside of there you get a bad instruction yet its of non optional type. What am I supposed to do about this?

Comment: A view controller requires either a valid nib document to load its view from (if you don't give it a name it will expect a nib with the name of the class, i.e. `PVC.nib`) _or_ you can set the `view` property before using it. The view property is non-optional because it should always be valid; not providing the view or nib is a programming error.

Comment: What should i initialize the view to? Just a generic NSView?

Comment: That sounds like a good place to start!

Answer (score 1):

You are not loading viewcontroller from either Storyboard or Xib.Try to initialise your viewcontroller from Storyboard/Xib if you are using. Then this will not get.

Comment: May i know why reputations were reduced?

Comment: This is not true see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319177/programmatically-create-an-nsviewcontroller-without-an-xib-in-swift-3